# How to load base64 image data from json in QT

Tags: c++, json, qt, gson

I am beginning with QT5 and trying to load an image from base64 json data. I can load directly from a base64 string but is unsuccessful when trying to load from json object.

the error i am getting is
error: conversion from 'QJsonValueRef' to non-scalar type 'QByteArray' requested

I tried changing toUtf8 toAcsii() etc. but similar error are being produced. Any help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll(); // json data from a servlet (created using gson library)
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();
QByteArray imgbase64 = jsonObj["photo"]; // image data
QImage img;
img.loadFromData(QByteArray::fromBase64(imgbase64));
ui->outputImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
ui->outputImage->setScaledContents( true );
ui->outputImage->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
```

Comment: `imgbase64 = jsonObj["photo"]` should return a simple string.  You can then convert the string into a binary byte array, which you can load into your image object.

Comment: won't the line img.loadFromData(QByteArray::fromBase64(imgbase64)); convert it to byte array?

Answer (score 1):

> error: conversion from 'QJsonValueRef' to non-scalar type 'QByteArray' requested*

Since you didn't specify this, I'm expect that the error you're seeing is coming from this line: -

```
QByteArray imgbase64 = jsonObj["photo"]; // image data
```

Calling the [] operator on a QJsonObject returns a [QJsonValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html). There is no overloaded = operator in QByteArray to initialise it from a QJsonValue.

What you need to do is use the QJsonValue functions and do something like this: -

```
QByteArray imgbase64;
if(jsonObj["photo"].isString())
{
    imgbase64 = jsonObj["photo"].toString().toUtf8();
}
```

Since the photo object is expected to be in Base64, it is acceptable as a string object.

Answer (score 1):

Following code converts JSON object image field to QString and QString to QImage -

```
QString base64img = jsonObj["photo"].toString();
QByteArray by = QByteArray::fromBase64(base64img.toLatin1());
QImage img = QImage::fromData(by,"JPEG");
```